# How can we set the profile option from a PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle10g

How can we set the profile option from a PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: Just to clarify for those (like me) who don't recognise the term "profile option", you are talking about an Oracle Applications feature here?

Comment: Profile option = to check the performance bottleneck of PL/SQL block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here for Oracle documentation on [PL/SQL Hierarchical Profiler](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm).

A very good example article from Oracle-base on [PL/SQL profiler.](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/PlsqlHierarchicalProfiler_11gR1.php) Are you dealing with Oracle 11gR1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PL/SQL Developer's [Profiler](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsprofiler.html)

[image]

Comment: Add the reason of you down voting. Be polite.

Comment: +1. Never know PL/SQL profiler existed in PL/SQL Developer. Gonna try it now.